# Why does JAXB differentiate elements and types?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

So, if you want to define a Java class from a Schema, you have to create a complex type for that Java class, and afterward you have to declare an XML element for that type.

```
<xs:complexType name="PersonType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="age" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="occupation" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="Person" type="myxml.PersonType"/>
```

---

**My question is, why does JAXB differentiate between complexType and element?** It seems to only create boilerplate code, where you have to nominally declare a class type twice.

For example, this would seem simpler (of course, it won't compile):

```
<xs:element name="Person">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="age" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="occupation" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:element>
```

Could someone please point out the design rationale behind this aspect of JAXB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **complex type** corresponds to the **class declaration**. The **element tag** corresponds to a **field declaration**. Looking at your example that may seem boilerplate, since you only "declare one field of a given type", however in more complex schemas it comes in handy.

E.g. if you want to represent a family, `PersonType` would be used for multiple elements:

```
<xs:complexType name="FamilyType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="father" type="PersonType"/>
        <xs:element name="mother" type="PersonType"/>
        <xs:element name="child" type="PersonType" maxOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="family" type="FamilyType"/>
```

Also the `element` is needed, if you want to use a type in a xml file (as topmost tag in a namespace).

In your case consider the following alternative:

```
<xs:element name="Person">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="age" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="occupation" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

By the way: XML-Schema was not designed especially for JAXB, JAXB was designed as a tool to be used with the already existing XML-Schema format.